# dhtmlx grid read-only checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, dhtmlx

I have set a column type in dhtmlx grid as below
`grid.setColumnExcellType( 0, 'ra');`

When I disable the column as : 
`grid.cellById(rowId, 0).setDisabled(true);`

The checkbox is shown disabled at first but as it is clicked it gets enabled. How can I disable the radio button completely so that even if it is clicked it does not get enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
grid.attachEvent("onEditCell", function(stage,rId,cInd,nValue,oValue){
        if (rId==rowId && cInd==0){
            return false;
        }
        else return true
    });
```